# Getting different outputs from equal inputs

Tags: java, processing

I am working with Processing 3.0.1. I want to check whether two 2D segments cross each other.

Each point is a "float[2]". The function receives four points (P1, P2, P3, P4) as parameters and checks it by solving the parametric equations for the lines P1P2, P3P4.

In one hand, I'm declaring four points in place:

```
float p1[] = new float[2];
p1[0] = 200.0;
p1[1] = 200.0;
float p2[] = new float[2];
p1[0] = 200.0;
p1[1] = 100.0;
float p3[] = new float[2];
p1[0] = 150.0;
p1[1] = 150.0;
float p4[] = new float[2];
p1[0] = 200.0;
p1[1] = 300.0;
System.out.println(cross(p1, p2, p3, p4));
```

It prints "false".

In the other hand, I create an array of points and initialize them.

```
float trian[][] = new float[3][2];
trian[0][0] = 150.0; 
trian[0][1] = 150.0;
trian[1][0] = 200.0; 
trian[1][1] = 300.0;
trian[2][0] = 300.0; 
trian[2][1] = 200.0;
float squar[][] = new float[4][2];
squar[0][0] = 100.0; 
squar[0][1] = 100.0;
squar[1][0] = 100.0; 
squar[1][1] = 200.0;
squar[2][0] = 200.0; 
squar[2][1] = 200.0;
squar[3][0] = 200.0; 
squar[3][1] = 100.0;
System.out.println(cross(squar[2], squar[3], trian[0], trian[1]));
```

It prints "true".

Why am I gettint different results? I put here my function for calculating it too (I have rechecked twice it is correct)

```
// Returns whether segments P1P2 and P3P4 cross or not
boolean cross(float p1[], float p2[], float p3[], float p4[]) {
    float x1 = p1[0];
    float y1 = p1[1];
    float x2 = p2[0];
    float y2 = p2[1];
    float x3 = p3[0];
    float y3 = p3[1];
    float x4 = p4[0];
    float y4 = p4[1];

    float den = (x2 - x1)*(y4 - y3) - (y2 - y1)*(x4 - x3);

    if (den == 0)
        return false;

    float num = (x2 - x1)*(y1 - y3) + (y2 - y1)*(x3 - x1);

    float k = num/den;

    if ((k >= 0) && (k <= 1))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: On your first example you're always setting p1. Never p2, p3 or p4.

Comment: Oh my god, shameful... Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already sorted your problem out, but in the future, it might help to use a `PVector` instead of an array with 2 indexes to keep track of your points:

```
PVector p1 = new PVector(200, 200);
PVector p2 = new PVector(200, 100);
PVector p3 = new PVector(150, 150);
```

You could then create a `Shape` class that kept track of points:

```
class Shape{
   ArrayList<PVector> points = new ArrayList<PVector>();

   public void addPoint(PVector p){
      points.add(p);
   }

   public void draw(){
      //draw the points
   }
}
```

Then to use that `Shape` class:

```
Shape triangle = new Shape();
triangle.addPoint(p1);
triangle.addPoint(p2);
triangle.addPoint(p3);
```

This will help you organize and encapsulate your data much better than using arrays will. This is the type of thing that objects were invented for, and they'll make your life a lot easier.